# .NET WPF Remember window size between sessions

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

Basically when user resizes my application's window I want application to be same size when application is re-opened again.

At first I though of handling SizeChanged event and save Height and Width, but I think there must be easier solution.

Pretty simple problem, but I can not find easy solution to it.

Comment: Please note that if you're resoring both the size and the *position*  (as most code samples below do), you'll want to handle the edge-case where someone unplugged the monitor that the window was last presented on, to avoid presenting your window off-screen.

Comment: @OmerRaviv Have you found an example taking the edge case in to account?

Comment: I have too less repution to add a comment, hence I created this new awnser. I use the same solution as **Lance Cleveland** including the setting of **RobJohnson**, but it doesn't work if you use it for sub windows and want to open more of them at the same time...

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Save the values in the user.config file.

You'll need to create the value in the settings file - it should be in the Properties folder. Create five values:

- `Top` of type `double`
- `Left` of type `double`
- `Height` of type `double`
- `Width` of type `double`
- `Maximized` of type `bool` - to hold whether the window is maximized or not. If you want to store more information then a different type or structure will be needed.

Initialise the first two to 0 and the second two to the default size of your application, and the last one to false.

Create a Window_OnSourceInitialized event handler and add the following:

```
this.Top = Properties.Settings.Default.Top;
this.Left = Properties.Settings.Default.Left;
this.Height = Properties.Settings.Default.Height;
this.Width = Properties.Settings.Default.Width;
// Very quick and dirty - but it does the job
if (Properties.Settings.Default.Maximized)
{
    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
```

**NOTE:** The set window placement needs to go in the on source initialised event of the window not the constructor, otherwise if you have the window maximised on a second monitor, it will always restart maximised on the primary monitor and you won't be able to access it.

Create a Window_Closing event handler and add the following:

```
if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
{
    // Use the RestoreBounds as the current values will be 0, 0 and the size of the screen
    Properties.Settings.Default.Top = RestoreBounds.Top;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Left = RestoreBounds.Left;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Height = RestoreBounds.Height;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Width = RestoreBounds.Width;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Maximized = true;
}
else
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Top = this.Top;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Left = this.Left;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Height = this.Height;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Width = this.Width;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Maximized = false;
}

Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

This will fail if the user makes the display area smaller - either by disconnecting a screen or changing the screen resolution - while the application is closed so you should add a check that the desired location and size is still valid before applying the values.

Comment: What if the application is installed under Program Files and the user is running as non-admin?

Comment: Sorry - I meant user.config which is stored under C:\Documents and Settings\\[user]\Local Settings\Application Data where the [User] should have access rights. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Actually, settings with scope "User" are not saved in the app.config file in Program Files, but in a user.config file in the user's application data directory. So it's not a problem...

Comment: I realised the mistake in the original answer when I saw Kent's comment and corrected it - probably at the same time you were adding your comment!

Comment: Actually you can add "WindowState" to settings. Select type -> browse -> PresentationFramework -> System.Windows -> WindowState :)

Comment: FWIW, I do this from the size changed handler as well, in case of application crashes.  They're rare with an unhandled exception processing, but why punish the user with lost size/location when they do mysteriously occur.

Comment: @MartyIX WindowState only manages maximize, minimized, or restored and does not address the size of window at all so I don't see how it is at all relavent.

Comment: There's a bug in this code in that, if the user opens the window on his/her second screen, then disconnects that screen from the computer, the next time they open the window, it will be presented off screen. If the window is modal, the user won't be able to interact with the app at all, and won't understand what's going on. You need to add a bounds check using Window.GetScreen(), after [converting the screen coordinates to DPI dependant values.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633759/ensuring-wpf-window-is-inside-screen-bounds)

Comment: @OmerRaviv - it's not a bug, but a limitation :) Seriously - I didn't address that aspect of the problem.

Comment: Not working.  If maximized on screen 2 when closed, it opens maximized on screen 1 when started.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu - you'll have to extend this to save which screen the application was closed on.

Comment: By the way, you must indeed not subscribe to `Window_Closed` instead of `Window_Closing`, although this might lead to a better user experience. For [_if you query `RestoreBounds` before the window has been shown or after it has been closed, `Empty` is returned._, like MSDN says.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.window.restorebounds(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: Since File Explorer displays this behavior, I was wondering if there's some automatic way of getting a window to do this, but I guess not.

Comment: `RestoreBounds` could also be used when the Window isn't maximized, so the if-else is not necessary

Comment: If your computer screen hardware setup changes some time (e.g. plug/unplug a second monitor to a laptop) I recommend to check if the loaded settings still fit. Look to methods `SizeToFit()` and `MoveIntoView()` of this [Code Project article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50761/Save-and-Restore-WPF-Window-Size-Position-and-or-S).

Comment: This does not work if the user snaps the Window

Answer (score 82):

Actually you don't need to use code-behind to do that (except for saving the settings). You can use a custom markup extension to bind the window size and position to the settings like this :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="Window1"
        Height="{my:SettingBinding Height}"
        Width="{my:SettingBinding Width}"
        Left="{my:SettingBinding Left}"
        Top="{my:SettingBinding Top}">
```

You can find the code for this markup extension here :
http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2008/11/18/wpf-binding-to-application-settings-using-a-markup-extension/

Comment: I like this answer more than the chosen accepted answer.  Well done.

Comment: +1 - I love the use of binding and extensions!  If you add the WindowState to your bound settings, it provides the full capabilities.  Alternatively, if you have the user settings available in the DataContext, you can use something like `{Binding Settings.Height}`, etc.

Comment: This approach have an issue when the user close the application when the Window is Maximized.

Comment: @Vinicius, can you elaborate? What is the issue exactly?

Comment: Hi @ThomasLevesque. When you maximize the window the values of width, height, left and top changes. So, if you close the application and then reopen it, the application wont remember the width/height/top/left from when it was in normal mode.

Comment: Let the OS do the heavy lifting... (see Andy's answer)

Comment: @Vinicius: I don't seem to have a problem with the app properly remembering width/height/top/left setting when closing the app while maximized.

Comment: But doesn't it still require us to write code behind (perhaps even more?) by writing a whole new extension/class?

Comment: What about when people have two monitors and thus it might have negative coordinates and then they change monitor configurations and the values are no longer valid?

Comment: To be clear, this works with both application and user settings, right? The link only says application settings.

Comment: I downloaded your sample from blog and that works and I am doing identical in a new application and somehow that doesn't work. Any idea if we need to do something more?

Answer (score 38):

While you can "roll your own" and manually save the settings somewhere, and in general it will work, it is very easy to not handle all of the cases correctly. It is much better to let the OS do the work for you, by calling [GetWindowPlacement()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633518(VS.85).aspx) at exit and [SetWindowPlacement()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633544(VS.85).aspx) at startup. It handles all of the crazy edge cases that can occur (multiple monitors, save the normal size of the window if it is closed while maximized, etc.) so that you don't have to.

[This MSDN Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972163.aspx) shows how to use these with a WPF app. The sample isn't perfect (the window will start in the upper left corner as small as possible on first run, and there is some odd behavior with the Settings designer saving a value of type `WINDOWPLACEMENT`), but it should at least get you started.

Comment: Nice solution. However I just discovered that GetWindowPlacement/SetWindowPlacement are [not Aero Snap aware](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1c3b7b79-8bb7-4824-95f9-e70f215e9313/remembering-window-placements-and-aero-snap?forum=wpf)

Comment: @RandomEngy has posted an improved answer based on this.

Answer (score 31):

The "long form" binding that Thomas posted above requires almost no coding, just make sure you have the namespace binding:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:p="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Properties"
        Title="Window1"
        Height="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=Height, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Width="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Left="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=Left, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Top="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=Top, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Then to save on the code-behind:

```
private void frmMain_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: I chose this solution, but only saved the settings if the window state was normal, otherwise it can be fiddly getting it out of maximised mode

Comment: +1 I used this too, @DavidSykes - Adding another setting for the window state seems to work well enough, e.g. `WindowState="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=WindowState, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: @RobJohnson I tried your suggestion and it worked very well, thanks.

Comment: I save on `Settings.Default.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => Settings.Default.Save()`, and add some delay `WindowState="{Binding MainWindow_WindowState, Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Delay=250, Mode=TwoWay}"` so it saves some SSD.

Comment: if you maximize the window on a second monitor, it is not restored on that same monitor on startup

Comment: This is the cleanest answer IMO, combined with the one-liner comment from @Palatis above; no markup extension required.  Adding `d:Height` and `d:Width` helps with consistent design-time sizing

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you might like the following approach too ([see source](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/erwyn/archive/2007/02/01/remembering-window-positions-in-wpf.aspx)). Add the WindowSettings class to your project and insert `WindowSettings.Save="True"` in your main window's header:

```
<Window x:Class="YOURPROJECT.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Services="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE.Services" 
    Services:WindowSettings.Save="True">
```

Where WindowSettings is defined as follows:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows;

namespace YOURNAMESPACE.Services
{
/// <summary>
///   Persists a Window's Size, Location and WindowState to UserScopeSettings
/// </summary>
public class WindowSettings
{
    #region Fields

    /// <summary>
    ///   Register the "Save" attached property and the "OnSaveInvalidated" callback
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SaveProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Save", typeof (bool), typeof (WindowSettings), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnSaveInvalidated));

    private readonly Window mWindow;

    private WindowApplicationSettings mWindowApplicationSettings;

    #endregion Fields

    #region Constructors

    public WindowSettings(Window pWindow) { mWindow = pWindow; }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Properties

    [Browsable(false)] public WindowApplicationSettings Settings {
        get {
            if (mWindowApplicationSettings == null) mWindowApplicationSettings = CreateWindowApplicationSettingsInstance();
            return mWindowApplicationSettings;
        }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods

    public static void SetSave(DependencyObject pDependencyObject, bool pEnabled) { pDependencyObject.SetValue(SaveProperty, pEnabled); }

    protected virtual WindowApplicationSettings CreateWindowApplicationSettingsInstance() { return new WindowApplicationSettings(this); }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Load the Window Size Location and State from the settings object
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void LoadWindowState() {
        Settings.Reload();
        if (Settings.Location != Rect.Empty) {
            mWindow.Left = Settings.Location.Left;
            mWindow.Top = Settings.Location.Top;
            mWindow.Width = Settings.Location.Width;
            mWindow.Height = Settings.Location.Height;
        }
        if (Settings.WindowState != WindowState.Maximized) mWindow.WindowState = Settings.WindowState;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Save the Window Size, Location and State to the settings object
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void SaveWindowState() {
        Settings.WindowState = mWindow.WindowState;
        Settings.Location = mWindow.RestoreBounds;
        Settings.Save();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Called when Save is changed on an object.
    /// </summary>
    private static void OnSaveInvalidated(DependencyObject pDependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs pDependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) {
        var window = pDependencyObject as Window;
        if (window != null)
            if ((bool) pDependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue) {
                var settings = new WindowSettings(window);
                settings.Attach();
            }
    }

    private void Attach() {
        if (mWindow != null) {
            mWindow.Closing += WindowClosing;
            mWindow.Initialized += WindowInitialized;
            mWindow.Loaded += WindowLoaded;
        }
    }

    private void WindowClosing(object pSender, CancelEventArgs pCancelEventArgs) { SaveWindowState(); }

    private void WindowInitialized(object pSender, EventArgs pEventArgs) { LoadWindowState(); }

    private void WindowLoaded(object pSender, RoutedEventArgs pRoutedEventArgs) { if (Settings.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized) mWindow.WindowState = Settings.WindowState; }

    #endregion Methods

    #region Nested Types

    public class WindowApplicationSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
    {
        #region Constructors

        public WindowApplicationSettings(WindowSettings pWindowSettings) { }

        #endregion Constructors

        #region Properties

        [UserScopedSetting] public Rect Location {
            get {
                if (this["Location"] != null) return ((Rect) this["Location"]);
                return Rect.Empty;
            }
            set { this["Location"] = value; }
        }

        [UserScopedSetting] public WindowState WindowState {
            get {
                if (this["WindowState"] != null) return (WindowState) this["WindowState"];
                return WindowState.Normal;
            }
            set { this["WindowState"] = value; }
        }

        #endregion Properties
    }

    #endregion Nested Types
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a [NuGet Project RestoreWindowPlace](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestoreWindowPlace)
 see on [github](https://github.com/Boredbone/RestoreWindowPlace) that does all this for you, saving the information in an XML file.

To get it to work on a window, it's as simple as calling:

`((App)Application.Current).WindowPlace.Register(this);`

In App you create the class that manages your windows. See the github link above for more information.

Comment: this package works great, and it's also handling minimized windows and disconnected monitors correctly. IMHO This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

I made a more generic solution based on RandomEngys brilliant answer. It saves the position to file in the running folder and you don't need to create new properties for each new window you create. This sollution works great for me with minimal code in code behind.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WindowPlacementNameSpace
{

    // RECT structure required by WINDOWPLACEMENT structure
    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;

        public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            this.Left = left;
            this.Top = top;
            this.Right = right;
            this.Bottom = bottom;
        }
    }

    // POINT structure required by WINDOWPLACEMENT structure
    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }

    // WINDOWPLACEMENT stores the position, size, and state of a window
    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
    {
        public int length;
        public int flags;
        public int showCmd;
        public POINT minPosition;
        public POINT maxPosition;
        public RECT normalPosition;
    }

    public static class WindowPlacement
    {
        private static readonly Encoding Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        private static readonly XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, out WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;

        private static void SetPlacement(IntPtr windowHandle, string placementXml)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(placementXml))
            {
                return;
            }

            byte[] xmlBytes = Encoding.GetBytes(placementXml);

            try
            {
                WINDOWPLACEMENT placement;
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes))
                {
                    placement = (WINDOWPLACEMENT)Serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
                }

                placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));
                placement.flags = 0;
                placement.showCmd = (placement.showCmd == SW_SHOWMINIMIZED ? SW_SHOWNORMAL : placement.showCmd);
                SetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, ref placement);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                // Parsing placement XML failed. Fail silently.
            }
        }

        private static string GetPlacement(IntPtr windowHandle)
        {
            WINDOWPLACEMENT placement;
            GetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, out placement);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    Serializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, placement);
                    byte[] xmlBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    return Encoding.GetString(xmlBytes);
                }
            }
        }
        public static void ApplyPlacement(this Window window)
        {
            var className = window.GetType().Name;
            try
            {
                var pos = File.ReadAllText(Directory + "\\" + className + ".pos");
                SetPlacement(new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle, pos);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Log.Error("Couldn't read position for " + className, exception);
            }

        }

        public static void SavePlacement(this Window window)
        {
            var className = window.GetType().Name;
            var pos =  GetPlacement(new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle);
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(Directory + "\\" + className + ".pos", pos);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Log.Error("Couldn't write position for " + className, exception);
            }
        }
        private static string Directory => Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    }
}
```

In your code behind you add these two methods

```
///This method is save the actual position of the window to file "WindowName.pos"
private void ClosingTrigger(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SavePlacement();
}
///This method is load the actual position of the window from the file
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    this.ApplyPlacement();
}
```

in the xaml window you add this

```
Closing="ClosingTrigger"
```

Answer (score 3):

The default way of solving it is to use settings files. The problem with settings files is that you have to define all the settings and write the code that copies data back and forth yourself. Quite tedious if you have a lot of properties to keep track of.

I made a pretty flexible and very easy to use library for this, you just tell it which properties of which object to track and it does the rest. You can configure the crap out of it too if you like.

The library is called **[Jot (github)](https://github.com/anakic/Jot)**, here is an old [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/475498/Easier-NET-settings) I wrote about it.

Here's how you'd use it to keep track of a window's size and location:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _stateTracker.Configure(this)
        .IdentifyAs("MyMainWindow")
        .AddProperties(nameof(Height), nameof(Width), nameof(Left), nameof(Top), nameof(WindowState))
        .RegisterPersistTrigger(nameof(Closed))
        .Apply();
}
```

**Jot vs. settings files:** With Jot there's considerably less code, and it's a lot less error prone since you only need to mention each property **once**. 
With settings files you need to mention each property **5 times**: once when you explicitly create the property and an additional four times in the code that copies the values back and forth.

Storage, serialization etc are completely configurable. Also, when using IOC, you can even hook it up so that it applies tracking automatically to all objects it resolves so that all you need to do to make a property persistent is slap a [Trackable] attribute on it.

I'm writing all this because I think the library is top notch and I want to mouth off about it.

Comment: Nice, thanks for this - I've used your code snippet in a new class to set up the state tracker with a path based on the program's name. From now on I only have to write one line and all the window properties are handled

Comment: Definitely check out the github page. This solution includes support for multiple monitors: https://github.com/anakic/Jot#real-world-formwindow-tracking

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a quick class which does this.  Here is how it's called:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        FormSizeSaver.RegisterForm(this, () => Settings.Default.MainWindowSettings,
                                   s =>
                                   {
                                       Settings.Default.MainWindowSettings = s;
                                       Settings.Default.Save();
                                   });
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
```

And here is the code:

```
public class FormSizeSaver
{
    private readonly Window window;
    private readonly Func<FormSizeSaverSettings> getSetting;
    private readonly Action<FormSizeSaverSettings> saveSetting;
    private FormSizeSaver(Window window, Func<string> getSetting, Action<string> saveSetting)
    {
        this.window = window;
        this.getSetting = () => FormSizeSaverSettings.FromString(getSetting());
        this.saveSetting = s => saveSetting(s.ToString());

        window.Initialized += InitializedHandler;
        window.StateChanged += StateChangedHandler;
        window.SizeChanged += SizeChangedHandler;
        window.LocationChanged += LocationChangedHandler;
    }

    public static FormSizeSaver RegisterForm(Window window, Func<string> getSetting, Action<string> saveSetting)
    {
        return new FormSizeSaver(window, getSetting, saveSetting);
    }


    private void SizeChangedHandler(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = getSetting();
        s.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
        s.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
        saveSetting(s);
    }

    private void StateChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = getSetting();
        if (window.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            if (!s.Maximized)
            {
                s.Maximized = true;
                saveSetting(s);
            }
        }
        else if (window.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
        {
            if (s.Maximized)
            {
                s.Maximized = false;
                saveSetting(s);
            }
        }
    }

    private void InitializedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = getSetting();
        window.WindowState = s.Maximized ? WindowState.Maximized : WindowState.Normal;

        if (s.Height != 0 && s.Width != 0)
        {
            window.Height = s.Height;
            window.Width = s.Width;
            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
            window.Left = s.XLoc;
            window.Top = s.YLoc;
        }
    }

    private void LocationChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = getSetting();
        s.XLoc = window.Left;
        s.YLoc = window.Top;
        saveSetting(s);
    }
}

[Serializable]
internal class FormSizeSaverSettings
{
    public double Height, Width, YLoc, XLoc;
    public bool Maximized;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, this);
            ms.Position = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)ms.Length];
            ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        }
    }

    internal static FormSizeSaverSettings FromString(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(value)))
            {
                var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                return (FormSizeSaverSettings) bf.Deserialize(ms);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new FormSizeSaverSettings();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: window.Intitialized should be window.Loaded see http://mostlytech.blogspot.com/2008/01/maximizing-wpf-window-to-second-monitor.html

Comment: @Gleb, both work I think.  Are you having problems with it on Initialized?

Comment: Yes, since maximized window will be on incorrect screen if you use only initialized event.
What I've done and this seems to work:

Now I'm subscribing to Loaded event also. 
I moved   _window.WindowState = s.Maximized ? WindowState.Maximized : WindowState.Normal; line inside "Loaded" event handler.

   window.Initialized += InitializedHandler;
   window.Loaded += LoadedHandler;

btw: I like this approach

Answer (score 1):

Create a string named WindowXml in your default Settings.

Use this extension method on your Window Loaded and Closing events to restore and save Window size and location.

```
using YourProject.Properties;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace YourProject.Extensions
{
    public static class WindowExtensions
    {
        public static void SaveSizeAndLocation(this Window w)
        {
            try
            {
                var s = "<W>";
                s += GetNode("Top", w.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized ? w.RestoreBounds.Top : w.Top);
                s += GetNode("Left", w.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized ? w.RestoreBounds.Left : w.Left);
                s += GetNode("Height", w.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized ? w.RestoreBounds.Height : w.Height);
                s += GetNode("Width", w.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized ? w.RestoreBounds.Width : w.Width);
                s += GetNode("WindowState", w.WindowState);
                s += "</W>";

                Settings.Default.WindowXml = s;
                Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        public static void RestoreSizeAndLocation(this Window w)
        {
            try
            {
                var xd = XDocument.Parse(Settings.Default.WindowXml);
                w.WindowState = (WindowState)Enum.Parse(typeof(WindowState), xd.Descendants("WindowState").FirstOrDefault().Value);
                w.Top = Convert.ToDouble(xd.Descendants("Top").FirstOrDefault().Value);
                w.Left = Convert.ToDouble(xd.Descendants("Left").FirstOrDefault().Value);
                w.Height = Convert.ToDouble(xd.Descendants("Height").FirstOrDefault().Value);
                w.Width = Convert.ToDouble(xd.Descendants("Width").FirstOrDefault().Value);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        private static string GetNode(string name, object value)
        {
            return string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best one yet - just need to call RestoreSizeAndLocation() from MainWindow() and after InitialiseComponent() otherwise there is a visible jump.

Answer (score 1):

Window location can be restored using an attached property that hooks `Closing` and writes to the registry.

Example of use (reference MIT Licensed [nuget `Esatto.Win32.CommonControls`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Esatto.Win32.CommonControls) or add the implementation below):

```
<Window x:Class="RememberWindowLocation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:win32="clr-namespace:Esatto.Win32.Wpf;assembly=Esatto.Win32.CommonControls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        win32:WindowPlacement.SavePath="Software\DemoApp\WindowPos">
</Window>
```

[MIT Licensed Implementation](https://github.com/mgaffigan/Esatto.Win32/blob/master/Esatto.Win32.CommonControls/Wpf/WindowPlacement.cs) which:

- Avoids restore if the window get's resized to be very small
- If monitor changes put it mostly outside of the desktop viewport
- Restores maximized if the window is closed when maximized
- Persists the restored size
- Never restores minimized

Source for copy/paste use (depends P/Invokes for `GetWindowPosition` and `EnumDisplayMonitors` available [in Github repo](https://github.com/mgaffigan/Esatto.Win32/blob/master/Esatto.Win32.CommonControls/Windows/NativeMethods.cs)):

```
// define debug for Debug.WriteLine to work
#define DEBUG

using Esatto.Win32.Windows;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace Esatto.Win32.Wpf
{
    public static class WindowPlacement
    {
        public static string GetSavePath(DependencyObject obj) => (string)obj.GetValue(SavePathProperty);

        public static void SetSavePath(DependencyObject obj, string value) => obj.SetValue(SavePathProperty, value);

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SavePathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SavePath", typeof(string), typeof(WindowPlacement),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, SavePath_Changed));

        private static void SavePath_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(d)) return;
            if (d is not Window wnd) throw new InvalidOperationException("WindowPlacement can only be applied to a Window");

            // Ensure idempotence
            wnd.Closing -= Window_Closing;
            wnd.Closing += Window_Closing;

            var newValue = (string)e.NewValue;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newValue))
            {
                try
                {
                    RestoreWindowLocation(wnd, newValue);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Could not restore window location for {wnd}: {ex}");
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancel) return;

            var window = (Window)sender;
            var savePath = GetSavePath(window);
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savePath)) return;
                if (window.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized) return;

                using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(savePath))
                {
                    var wp = Windows.NativeMethods.GetWindowPlacement(new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle);
                    key.SetValue(nameof(window.WindowState), (int)window.WindowState);
                    key.SetValue(nameof(window.Left), wp.NormalPosition.left);
                    key.SetValue(nameof(window.Top), wp.NormalPosition.top);
                    key.SetValue(nameof(window.Width), wp.NormalPosition.Width);
                    key.SetValue(nameof(window.Height), wp.NormalPosition.Height);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Could not save window location for {window}: {ex}");
            }
        }

        private static void RestoreWindowLocation(Window window, string savePath)
        {
            WindowState state;
            var pos = new Rect();
            using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(savePath))
            {
                var oState = key.GetValue(nameof(window.WindowState));
                if (oState is null) return;
                state = (WindowState)(int)oState;

                pos.X = (int)key.GetValue(nameof(window.Left), 0);
                pos.Y = (int)key.GetValue(nameof(window.Top), 0);
                pos.Width = (int)key.GetValue(nameof(window.Width), 0);
                pos.Height = (int)key.GetValue(nameof(window.Height), 0);
            }

            // verify that the size is "reasonable"
            if ((pos.Width * pos.Height) < 2 /* in^2 */ * 96 * 96 /* dpi^2 */)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Omitting restore of location for {window} due to {pos} being too small to restore");
                return;
            }

            double IntersectionPercentage(Rect a, Rect b)
            {
                if (!a.IntersectsWith(b)) return 0d;
                b.Intersect(a);
                return (b.Width * b.Height) / (a.Width * a.Height);
            }
            var mostlyOn = (
                from monitor in MonitorInfo.GetAllMonitors()
                let overlap = IntersectionPercentage(pos, monitor.ViewportBounds)
                // only consider a monitor if more than 75% of the window is showing
                where overlap > 0.75d
                // pick the highest overlapping monitor
                orderby overlap descending
                select monitor
            ).FirstOrDefault();

            if (mostlyOn is null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Omitting restore of location for {window} due to {pos} being offscreen");
                return;
            }

            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
            window.Left = pos.Left;
            window.Top = pos.Top;
            window.Width = pos.Width;
            window.Height = pos.Height;
            window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

            // https://nikola-breznjak.com/blog/quick-tips/maximizing-a-wpf-window-to-second-monitor/
            if (state == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                window.Loaded += Window_MaximizeOnFirstLoaded;
            }
        }

        private static void Window_MaximizeOnFirstLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (Window)sender;
            window.Loaded -= Window_MaximizeOnFirstLoaded;

            window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like this:

```
public class WindowStateHelper
{
    public static string ToXml(System.Windows.Window win)
    {
        XElement bounds = new XElement("Bounds");
        if (win.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            bounds.Add(new XElement("Top", win.RestoreBounds.Top));
            bounds.Add(new XElement("Left", win.RestoreBounds.Left));
            bounds.Add(new XElement("Height", win.RestoreBounds.Height));
            bounds.Add(new XElement("Width", win.RestoreBounds.Width));
        }
        else
        {
            bounds.Add(new XElement("Top", win.Top));
            bounds.Add(new XElement("Left", win.Left));
            bounds.Add(new XElement("Height", win.Height));
            bounds.Add(new XElement("Width", win.Width));
        }
        XElement root = new XElement("WindowState",
            new XElement("State", win.WindowState.ToString()),
            new XElement("Visibility", win.Visibility.ToString()),
            bounds);

        return root.ToString();
    }

    public static void FromXml(string xml, System.Windows.Window win)
    {
        try
        {
            XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);
            string state = root.Descendants("State").FirstOrDefault().Value;
            win.WindowState = (System.Windows.WindowState)Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Windows.WindowState), state);

            state = root.Descendants("Visibility").FirstOrDefault().Value;
            win.Visibility = (System.Windows.Visibility)Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Windows.Visibility), state);

            XElement bounds = root.Descendants("Bounds").FirstOrDefault();
            win.Top = Convert.ToDouble(bounds.Element("Top").Value);
            win.Left = Convert.ToDouble(bounds.Element("Left").Value);
            win.Height = Convert.ToDouble(bounds.Element("Height").Value);
            win.Width = Convert.ToDouble(bounds.Element("Width").Value);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When the app closes:

```
        Properties.Settings.Default.Win1Placement = WindowStateHelper.ToXml(win1);
        Properties.Settings.Default.Win2Placement = WindowStateHelper.ToXml(win2);
        ...
```

When the app starts:

```
        WindowStateHelper.FromXml(Properties.Settings.Default.Win1Placement, win1);
        WindowStateHelper.FromXml(Properties.Settings.Default.Win2Placement, win2);
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the answer from Lance Cleveland and bind the Setting.
But i'm using some more Code to avoid that my Window is out of Screen.

```
private void SetWindowSettingsIntoScreenArea()
{
    // first detect Screen, where we will display the Window
    // second correct bottom and right position
    // then the top and left position.
    // If Size is bigger than current Screen, it's still possible to move and size the Window

    // get the screen to display the window
    var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromPoint(new System.Drawing.Point((int)Default.Left, (int)Default.Top));

    // is bottom position out of screen for more than 1/3 Height of Window?
    if (Default.Top + (Default.Height / 3) > screen.WorkingArea.Height)
        Default.Top = screen.WorkingArea.Height - Default.Height;

    // is right position out of screen for more than 1/2 Width of Window?
    if (Default.Left + (Default.Width / 2) > screen.WorkingArea.Width)
        Default.Left = screen.WorkingArea.Width - Default.Width;

    // is top position out of screen?
    if (Default.Top < screen.WorkingArea.Top)
        Default.Top = screen.WorkingArea.Top;

    // is left position out of screen?
    if (Default.Left < screen.WorkingArea.Left)
        Default.Left = screen.WorkingArea.Left;
}
```