# Get size from ShowDialog

Tags: .net, wpf, showdialog

The user may change the size and position of the NavigationWindow
I want to capture the Height, Width, Left, and Right when the user closes the dialog
How can I do that?

```
NavigationWindow help = new NavigationWindow();
help.Content = new PageHelp2("Fields");
help.Height = 600;
help.Width = 800;
help.ShowDialog();
```

The purpose is the next time they are shown help to bring it up with the last size and position.

Comment: That is not something `ShowDialog()` returns. Do you want to [Remember window size between session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847752/net-wpf-remember-window-size-between-sessions)?

Comment: @CodeCaster I already do that with their mainwindow.  Within a session when they bring up help the next time they bring it up help I want have it the same size and position.

Comment: So do the same for all of your windows.  :)

Comment: Same size and position anytime they bring up the "help" window.  Now "help" may be about about different topics - passed in the ctor.

Comment: Yes of course, if you refer to the same variable for all windows, they'll have the same size and position. If you want it to be unique per help topic, you'll have to save the coordinates in a dictionary for example, like `"Help_Fields_X"`, `"Help_Foos_X"`. The answer you your question stated as-is is "You can't", if you want help fixing your code you should show your code.

Comment: @CodeCaster The question is not how to set or save the values.  The question is how to capture those values when the NavigationWindow is closed.

Comment: So your question is not _"How can I find and restore the window size?"_, but _"How can I detect window closure?"_? Then you might want to update your question to reflect that.

Comment: The question is "I want to capture the Height, Width, Left, and Right when the user closes the dialog".

Comment: And I'm saying that from your question it isn't clear what part _specifically_ you need help with. Is the problem subscribing to a Closing/Closed event, like I demonstrate in my answer? Is it accessing the properties `Width`, `Height` and so on? Is it storing the values and restoring them upon the next `ShowDialog()`?

Comment: Specifically I needed help with "capture the Height, Width, Left, and Right when the user closes the dialog".  Thanks for the answer.  It is a direct answer to the stated question as I understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the moment a window is closing using the [`Window.Closing` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Window.Closed` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Be sure to read the remarks for the former, as the event won't always be raised.

```
public void ShowHelp()
{
    NavigationWindow help = new NavigationWindow();
    help.Closing += HelpWindow_Closing;
    help.Content = new PageHelp2("Fields");
    //
    help.ShowDialog();
}

void HelpWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var window = sender as Window;

    // Do your thing
    window.Height;
    window.Width;
}
```