# How to separate View data and ViewModel data?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to manage UI specific parameters (View) and Application data (Model/ViewModel) separately, so I'm using the code-behind of the View for the first, and a separated class (prefixed ViewModel) for the later. This is an simplified version of what I have:

**View (XAML)**

```
<Window x:Class="UrSimulator.View.MyView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MyView" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding FirstColumnWidth}" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>Width:</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstColumnWidth}" IsReadOnly="True" Background="LightGray" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <Label>First Column Width:</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstColumnWidth}" />
        <Label>View Model Data:</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyViewModel.PropertyFromVM}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding MyViewModel.PropertyFromVM}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**View (Code behind)**

```
public partial class MyView : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private MyViewModel m_MyViewModel;
    public MyViewModel MyViewModel
    {
        get { return m_MyViewModel; }
        set
        {
            m_MyViewModel = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyViewModel"));
        }
    }

    private GridLength m_FirstColumnWidth;
    public GridLength FirstColumnWidth
    {
        get { return m_FirstColumnWidth; }
        set
        {
            m_FirstColumnWidth = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstColumnWidth"));
        }
    }

    public MyView()
    {
        MyViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        DataContext = this;
        FirstColumnWidth = new GridLength(100);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string m_PropertyFromVM;
    public string PropertyFromVM
    {
        get { return m_PropertyFromVM; }
        set
        {
            m_PropertyFromVM = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PropertyFromVM"));
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        PropertyFromVM = "Some business data";
    }
}
```

It works, but I find it cumbersome to use `MyViewModel.` on every binding that points to the VM.

**Questions:**

Is there another way to do this without using the prefix?

How should I write the binding for the UI (the width property) if instead of using `this` for the DataContext, I'd use:

```
DataContext = MyViewModel;
```

I'm doing everything wrong and this is not how it is intended to be?

**Note:** Forget about the converter needed for the Width, it works as long as the text is valid and is not my concern on the question.

Comment: See this thread for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847752/net-wpf-remember-window-size-between-sessions `SettingBinding` seems pretty cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DataContext = this;
```

Yuck... :)

Let the view model be the data context, and bind on your view's properties like this :

```
<Window x:Name="This" ...>
   ...
   <SomeControl SomeProperty="{Binding MyViewProperty, ElementName=This}"/>
   ...
</Window>
```

*Side note :*

```
class MyView : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Why aren't your view's properties "dependency properties" if you inherit Window ?

Comment: I think that I don't need full DP but simple INPC properties do the trick so I don't want to bloat the View with DP when they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing MVVM, but not a great choice as you are still using tightly coupled `View` objects.

The ideal is where you let WPF infer what `View` class to use by binding your `ViewModel` objects to the `Content` property of `ContentPresenters` and setting up `DataTemplate` entries for your `ViewModel` types.

That way, you don't even need to use a `DataContext = blah` statement in your code anywhere.

e.g. in the App.xaml or similar

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type MyViewModel}>
  <local:MyViewModelView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

... then in the Window/UserControl/XAML wherever you need it...

```
<ContentPresenter Content={Binding MyViewModelAsAProperty}/>
```

...which can be a `DependencyProperty` or a standard `INotifyPropertyChanged` enabled property on another `ViewModel`.

Answer (score -1):

Add this codes on your MyViewModel Class

```
private MyView _ObjMyViewModel;
public MyView ObjMyViewModel
{
    get { return _ObjMyViewModel; }
    set
    {
        _ObjMyViewModel= value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ObjMyViewModel"));
    }
}
```

And in XAML

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ObjMyViewModel.FirstColumnWidth}" />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<StackPanel>
    <Label>Width:</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ObjMyViewModel.FirstColumnWidth}" IsReadOnly="True" Background="LightGray" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <Label>First Column Width:</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ObjMyViewModel.FirstColumnWidth}" />
    <Label>View Model Data:</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyViewModel.PropertyFromVM}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding MyViewModel.PropertyFromVM}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I hope its working..