# F# persist some user values for WPF app

Tags: wpf, f#

In my small WPF app (F# only) I would like to remember the window size and location after closing. [This C# solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847752/net-wpf-remember-window-size-between-sessions) suggest to use the projects settings IDictinary for User.config. This looks like the simple approach that I am after but I did not find the project settings in my F# project. Do they exist for F# projects?

I tried this but it does not work: (The save() call as in the C# example is not available.)

```
let getSetting k def = 
    if Application.Current.Properties.Contains k 
       then Application.Current.Properties.Item k 
       else def

let window = System.Windows.Window()
// is box() the best wax to make floats into obj ?
window.Top <-     getSetting "WindowTop"    (box 0.0) |> unbox  
window.Left <-    getSetting "WindowLeft"   (box 0.0) |> unbox 
window.Height <-  getSetting "WindowHeight" (box 800.0) |> unbox  
window.Width <-   getSetting "WindowWidth"  (box 800.0) |> unbox

window.Closing.Add( fun _ -> 
      Application.Current.Properties.Add("WindowTop",window.Top)
      Application.Current.Properties.Add("WindowHeight",window.Height)
      Application.Current.Properties.Add("WindowLeft",window.Left)
      Application.Current.Properties.Add("WindowWidth",window.Width)
      //Application.Current.Properties.Save() // not available!
      )
```

I know I could use a [type provider](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/AppSettingsProvider.html) but I would like to keep it simple and without dependencies if possible. Is there a built in way to persist some user values in an F# WPF app?

Comment: Properties.Settings.Default refers to the Settings class that is generated from the Properties->Setting.settings file that is included in the project template from a WPF application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @mm8 points out, the approach you mention depends on the *Settings.settings* file included in the project template of a C# WPF app.

[image: C# WPF App]

The F# template does not provide such functionality, which is unfortunate given the XAML support is pretty cool. Instead, you could resort to the *App.config* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  ...

  <appSettings>
    <add key="WindowTop" value="0" />
    <add key="WindowLeft" value="0" />
    <add key="WindowHeight" value="350" />
    <add key="WindowWidth" value="525" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

If you don't want to depend on *FSharp.Configuration.dll* you can use the `ConfigurationManager` (note you still need to add a reference to *System.Configuration.dll*).

```
open System.Configuration

type UserSettings = {
    WindowTop    : float
    WindowLeft   : float
    WindowHeight : float
    WindowWidth  : float
  } with 
    static member Load() =
      let config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
      { // To do: add validation
        WindowTop    = float config.AppSettings.Settings.["WindowTop"].Value 
        WindowLeft   = float config.AppSettings.Settings.["WindowLeft"].Value
        WindowHeight = float config.AppSettings.Settings.["WindowHeight"].Value
        WindowWidth  = float config.AppSettings.Settings.["WindowWidth"].Value
      }
    member this.Save() =
      let config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
      config.AppSettings.Settings.["WindowTop"].Value     <- string this.WindowTop
      config.AppSettings.Settings.["WindowLeft"].Value    <- string this.WindowLeft
      config.AppSettings.Settings.["WindowHeight"].Value  <- string this.WindowHeight
      config.AppSettings.Settings.["WindowWidth"].Value   <- string this.WindowWidth
      config.Save()
```

Now you can:

```
open System.Windows

let window = new Window()    
let settings = UserSettings.Load()

window.Top    <- settings.WindowTop
window.Left   <- settings.WindowLeft
window.Height <- settings.WindowHeight
window.Width  <- settings.WindowWidth

window.Closing.Add( fun _ -> 
  {
    WindowTop    = window.Top
    WindowLeft   = window.Left
    WindowHeight = window.Height
    WindowWidth  = window.Width
  }.Save() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer of Funk I came up with this as the minimal general solution using `System.Configuration.dll`:

```
module Config = 
    open System.Configuration
    let private config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

    let save key value = 
        try  config.AppSettings.Settings.[key].Value <- value 
        with _ -> config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key,value) // in case key does not exist yet
        config.Save()

    let load key  = 
        try  Some config.AppSettings.Settings.[key].Value 
        with _ -> None
```