# "shutdown.exe" destroys application settings

Tags: c#, wpf, batch-file, shutdown, application-settings

I have a one-window WPF application (Win8.1 / .net4.7), the Window.Closing-Event is unhandled, the Window.Closed-Event is handled as follows:

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.WinMainLocationX = this.Left; // ok
    Properties.Settings.Default.WinMainLocationY = this.Top; // ok
    Properties.Settings.Default.WinMain_size = new Size(this.Width, this.Height); // crucial setting
    Properties.Settings.Default.WinMain_state = this.WindowState; // ok

    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

I'm closing the app (at this point always in idle state) once a day by a batch file containing `C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe /s /t 20` and nothing afterwards. By this the computer shuts down properly. The parameters of `shutdown.exe` can be seen by command line input of `shutdown /?`.

Problem: Every 7 or 8 days the window size gets corrupted in a way that the application (after having started in the morning) looks like this:

[image]

How can I protect my application settings from interference by `shutdown.exe`?

Comment: Where is the code that positions the window from the settings?

Comment: You may try to move your code to an event handler for the [Application.Exit](https://wpf.2000things.com/2010/08/29/48-handling-an-applications-exit-event/) event. It should be fired when the application is shutting down or the Windows session is ending. There is no guarantee that your data will always be properly saved before the session is terminating though.

Comment: This machine needs a better anti-malware product or should not be shut down automatically.  You could use taskkill.exe in the .bat file so the product has enough time to complete the XML scan.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET WPF Remember window size between sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847752/net-wpf-remember-window-size-between-sessions)

Comment: @mm8: Thanks for your advice, I didn't check it out since a one liner has solved the issue in the meantime.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for your advice, I didn't check it out since a one liner has solved the issue in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is storing the settings while the application window is minimized. Width and Height of the window will be 0 in this case.

You can use the [`RestoreBounds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.restorebounds) property of your window to get its restored size independent of its current state:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.WinMainLocationX = this.RestoreBounds.Left; 
Properties.Settings.Default.WinMainLocationY = this.RestoreBounds.Top;
Properties.Settings.Default.WinMain_size = new Size(this.RestoreBounds.Width, this.RestoreBounds.Height);
Properties.Settings.Default.WinMain_state = this.WindowState;
```

---

Some answers to this question show another approach using the WinAPI functions `GetWindowPlacement` / `SetWindowPlacement`:

- [.NET WPF Remember window size between sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847752/net-wpf-remember-window-size-between-sessions)

Comment: Meanwhile I've tried your proposal with `RestoreBounds.Width` and `RestoreBounds.Height` inside the Closing-Handler and it works. I like this solution better.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Environment.Exit(0)`has solved the issue. I can imagine the cause of the problem was that the Window.Closed-Handler has been reached twice.

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.WinMainLocationX = this.Left; // ok
    Properties.Settings.Default.WinMainLocationY = this.Top; // ok
    Properties.Settings.Default.WinMain_size = new Size(this.Width, this.Height); // crucial setting
    Properties.Settings.Default.WinMain_state = this.WindowState; // ok

    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```