# How to know Last Window-Startup-Location When it was just closed ? WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm Working on a WPF application which automatically restart after specific interval of time (I'm using DispatcherTimer for that purpose). The problem is how to know WPF window's last Startup_Location.. Because I needed to set that location when it restart..

(I have set Default Startup_Location "CenterOwner" in XAML code like

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
```

but if user change that location then I need to know that location to set when WPF restart)

Secondly How to know WPF window was minimized last time as this is also need to set when it restart
Thanks

Comment: You can save the required info in an xml file before window closes, and read the info from xml before loading the window again.

Comment: Thanks for reply @MathivananKP .. 
How to save that info in xmal and apply when it reload ?
I'm new in WPF..

Comment: You can save the state in userconfig file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847761/4395187) is how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, you will have to store the attributes of the window to persist them between the starts. In order to set the location of the `Window` you have to set `WindowStartupLocation` to `WindowStartupLocation.Manual`. You would have to start the main window manually from the *App.xaml.cs*.

In order to change the way WPF starts your application, you have to modify the *App.xaml* and change the active property `StartupUri` to the event handler property `Startup` and assign a handler method to it (in this case named `Run`):

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTestRange.Main.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Run">
</Application>
```

Then implement the handler in the *App.xaml.cs* and start the main window manually:

```
private void Run(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  this.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
  this.MainWindow.Closing += SaveWindowAttributes;
  RestoreWindow();
  this.MainWindow.Show();
}

protected void RestoreWindow()
{
  this.MainWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
  var reader = new AppSettingsReader();

  string windowStateValue;
  try
  {
    windowStateValue = reader.GetValue("WindowState", typeof(string)) as string;
  }
  catch (InvalidOperationException)
  {
    // There are no previously persisted values (first launch)
    return;
  }

  WindowState windowState;
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(windowStateValue) && Enum.TryParse(windowStateValue, out windowState))
  {
    this.MainWindow.WindowState = windowState;
  }

  string windowTopValue = reader.GetValue("WindowPositionTop", typeof(string)) as string;
  string windowLeftValue = reader.GetValue("WindowPositionLeft", typeof(string)) as string;

  double windowPositionTop;
  double windowPositionLeft;
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(windowStateValue) 
      && double.TryParse(windowTopValue, out windowPositionTop) 
      && double.TryParse(windowLeftValue, out windowPositionLeft))
  {
    this.MainWindow.Top = windowPositionTop;
    this.MainWindow.Left = windowPositionLeft;
  }

}

private void SaveWindowAttributes(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  string sectionName = "appSettings";
  Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

  string currentWindowState = this.MainWindow.WindowState.ToString();
  if (config.AppSettings.Settings["WindowState"] == null)
  {
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("WindowState", currentWindowState);
  }
  else
  {
    config.AppSettings.Settings["WindowState"].Value = currentWindowState;
  }

  string currentWindowPositionTop = this.MainWindow.Top.ToString("G");
  if (config.AppSettings.Settings["WindowPositionTop"] == null)
  {
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("WindowPositionTop", currentWindowPositionTop);
  }
  else
  {
    config.AppSettings.Settings["WindowPositionTop"].Value = currentWindowPositionTop;
  }

  string currentWindowPositionLeft = this.MainWindow.Left.ToString("G");
  if (config.AppSettings.Settings["WindowPositionLeft"] == null)
  {
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("WindowPositionLeft", currentWindowPositionLeft);
  }
  else
  {
    config.AppSettings.Settings["WindowPositionLeft"].Value = currentWindowPositionLeft;
  }
  config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
  ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionName);
}
```

Comment: @BilalTahir I edited the answer to show this step.